# Error with managed C++ calling C# function : While having "out" type

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have C++/CLI code that needs to call a C# method.

The C# code is something like this:

```
class Coordinates
{
double latitude;
double longitude;
}

class ErorWarningData
{
string errorWarning;
}
```

The C# method signature is like this :
    Coordinates GetInfo(string custNum, out ErrorWarningData);

How can I specify the ErrorWarningData object to be "out" from my C++/CLI code and call the C# method ??

Comment: What is the C++ signature exactly?  You cannot send an object to the managed C++ code unless its actually expecting an object and based on what you posted your C# signature is expecting a string.

Comment: @David - Wouldn't a reference parameter be used in the case of an 'in' parameter?

Comment: Well, Google reveals that it's a dupe, but the good news is that there is an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to.  In C++ (and also C++/CLI), reference parameters don't require any special syntax at the caller (Some of us consider that a bad thing, because it isn't obvious the parameter will be changed by the call).

Comment: If he is going to take the default calling convention of C++ he needs to change the calling convention of his C# to match or otherwise match the calling convention in his C++ code. The default calling conventions do not match between C++ and C#.  Unless this is only true for unmanaged C++ code :$

Comment: @Ramhound: C++/CLI understands the metadata created by the C# compiler.  It will use the right calling convention (`clrcall`).